# TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df' when using data.head() for a dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to execute `data.head()` to view a dask dataframe and get the following error:
`TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'df'`

This error specifically occurs after executing a lambda function using map_partitions (shown in the code below) that attempts to add a column to the dataframe. I can see the new column added to the dask dataframe structure by this line, however data.head() fails.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser

data['text'] = dd.map_partitions(
    lambda df : df.apply(
        lambda x : HTMLParser(x['text']).body.text(separator=' '
            ).replace('\n',' '),axis=1),
    meta='str')
data.head()
```

In my notebook data.head() works until I execute this line so I am suspecting the error occurs in the line executing map_partitions().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You very likely wanted `data.map_partitions`, i.e., the method on the dataframe rather than the function you used.

Also, it looks a lot like you could have used a simple `map` here:

```
data['text'] = data.text.map(
    lambda x: HTMLParser(x).body.text(separator=' '
        ).replace('\n',' ')
)
```

(although I may be misunderstanding what your code does)

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion worked I had written that line following this article [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-i-learned-to-love-parallelized-applies-with-python-pandas-dask-and-numba-f06b0b367138) but the change you suggested definitely makes much more sense.